# 480VAC to 230VAC AC AC conversion

Tags: capacitor, motor, ac, voltage-source

I want to drive a single phase motor (230V, 260mA) on a 480VAC (phase to phase) source.
I made this simple circuit using a 2uF, 600V AC capacitor, simulated it, tested practically and it is working as per the simulation.
[image]

My motor driving interval is nearly 10 times a day for 10 seconds.

1. Is this good way to driver motor?
2. Any possible failure?
3. What should I do to protect the circuit and motor?

Thanks

Comment: cant you connect it to Neutral directly ?

Comment: Well it's theorically correct as a reactance dropper. If the capacitor is good there should be no problems, the motor isn't really a big load. Protection is the same as for a standalone motor: delayed fuse and maybe thermal overload depending on the kind of work it does

Comment: @tobalt Input is delta connection only.

Comment: The worry is that it may not be able to supply high current to drive the starting torque required of the motor. In which case ... stalled motor. Rate the other components to survive a short circuited motor.

Comment: @user_1818839 If motor is short circuited, I don't see any issue, but if capacitor become short circuit, it will destroy everything, thus will add 500mA PPTC and 2Amp fuse before capacitor.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not a good way tor drive a motor, but it might work. A very small AC motor could be simply modeled as an inductance with a variable resistance in series. The resistance variation would need to vary to model the effect the load. Most of the variation would be seen during starting. The fact that very small motors are not very efficient will reduce the magnitude of resistance variation.

The 480V source is not correctly modeled. What you have shown results in 416 volts. You could use a single 480V source.

Motors that small are usually not protected unless there is a thermal fuse imbedded in the winding by the manufacturer. The driving circuit and wiring wiring could be protected by a fuse.

Comment: Thanks, yes, 416V is incorrect. I have to tune it for 480V.  I am looking for simple low cost however reasonably durable solution. I will add 2Amp fuse, S14K550, 550V MOV and PPTC (500mA) to protect the circuit and motor.